# Keep the head of a singly linked list in Java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Say there is a singly linked list:
1->2->3->4->null

Definition for singly-linked list:

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) {
        val = x;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

If I want to print the node value one by one from head to tail, I need to use head = head.next iteratively until head == null. In this case, we can never return to the head(value=1) node after printing.
My question is how to keep the head while traversing the singly linked list?

Comment: `ListNode head = theHead;` -- Just stick it in a variable before you traverse the list.

Comment: I thought this problem complicatedly. Thanks, Jason~!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple Answer: Create a reference to the head, and traverse that. That way you never lose that reference to the head.

Example:

```
ListNode iter = head;
while(iter.next != null){
    //DO Stuff
    iter = iter.next;
}
```

Note now that the head variable is never changed. It is ready to be used as before.

Comment: Fixed. Damn terminology :p

Comment: I thought this problem complicatedly. Thanks~!